# Xcode/iOS intern version number, which version number is smaller?

Tags: ios, xcode, version-control

I have a version 1.1.1 and I need to increase the number to upload to the App Store. My question is, which number is smaller: 1.1.11 or 1.1.2? Are the numbers between the decimals treated as ints or does it follow normal decimal rules? Pretty much is 1.1.2 == 1.1.20? Its a small update and I don't want to raise the version number more than I have to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each number is treated as an integer. So 1.1.11 is 1, 1, and 11. And 1.1.20 is 1, 1, and 20.

So 1.1.2 is smaller than 1.1.11 since 2 < 11 and both start with 1 and 1.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, that's what I thought but this is my first app so wanted to be safe than stuck with a large version number for no reason :)